# x86_64 crash because incorrect bytecode

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, crash-dumps, sse2

I try to find the root cause of an infrequent crash. I build code on win32 while run on win64. The compiler of my native simd code is nasm, the command line is

```
nasm -f win32 -DPREFIX -I./asm/  -o $(IntDir)%(Filename).obj %(FullPath)
```

The original source code is

```
****22fd   66 0F 38 1D C0       pabsw       xmm0,xmm0  
****2302   66 0F FD E8          paddw       xmm5,xmm0  
****2306   66 0F 70 45 20 EE    pshufd      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp+20h],0EEh
****230c   66 0F 6C C0          punpcklqdq  xmm0,xmm0
```

but crash dmp file show incorrect bytecode (occurs rarely, once on Intel i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz)

```
****1e9d   66 0F 38 1D C0              pabsw       xmm0,xmm0  
****1ea2   66 0F FD E8                 paddw       xmm5,xmm0  
****1ea6   66 0F 70 05 20 EE 66 0F 6c  pshufd      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[0F66EE20h],6Ch  // crash!
```

It seems byecode is incorrect, while windbg !chkimg show no error.
Whether the cause is related to REX prefix or I should use "BITS 32" explicitly on head of .asm file?
Any suggestion is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a single bit error. Check your memory and disk?

Comment: thanks for you reply. Actually it's customer's CPU, which crash 3 times on same address, BUT after restart the case disappear. While it's unreasonable to access info about memory and disk until strong enough reason/clue. I'll see whether reoccurs. Thanks!